# Android studio not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio for Linux from here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have Java version 1.7.0_21:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I start Android Studio ./bin/studio.sh I get a little dialog with the Android logo and a progress bar. When that completes, I get a blank window (I assume that's the main window of Android Studio), but I do get another little dialog, which looks correct, showing me a tip about Android Studio.

So basically I cannot interact with the main window of Android Studio because it's completely blank.

These are some crashes that I see in the shell when running ./bin/studio.sh

```
$ ./bin/studio.sh 
org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException: Key org.jetbrains.generate.tostring.template.TemplatesManager duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:143)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.registerComponent(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.addExtensionPointListener(ExtensionPointImpl.java:342)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.installEP(ServiceManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.<init>(ServiceManagerImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:524)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:150)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:43)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException: Key org.jetbrains.generate.tostring.GenerateToStringContext duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:143)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.registerComponent(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.addExtensionPointListener(ExtensionPointImpl.java:342)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.installEP(ServiceManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.<init>(ServiceManagerImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:524)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:150)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:43)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
[   2344]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - action with the ID "com.google.gct.intellij.endpoints.MenuGroup" was already registered. Action being registered is null (null); Registered action is Google Cloud Endpoints (Endpoints Actions) 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:946)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:919)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:970)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processGroupElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionsChildElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:896)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:524)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:150)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:43)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:696)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
[   2347]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Android Studio (I/O Preview) 0.3.7  Build #AI-132.932373 
[   2347]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.7.0_21 
[   2347]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[   2347]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   2348]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Linux 
[   2348]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - action with the ID "Actions.ActionsPlugin.GenerateToString" was already registered. Action being registered is toString() (Generate toString() method); Registered action is toString() (Generate toString() method) Plugin: GenerateToString [Plugin: GenerateToString]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried installing Android Studio in my laptop, which is also running Ubuntu 12.04 and got the same problem. Blank window. But in this case I don't get all the crashes pasted above, so I guess the crashes are not related to the actual problem.

Comment: did you get solution of this problem or still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

When we see problems like this, it's quite often due to video driver problems, window manager problems, or other things going on in the OS. A lot of users who report issues where parts of the UI don't render tend to fix them by looking at those sorts of things, and it tends to be a different resolution for each user because the exact problem is different in every case. I'd encourage you to look hard for updated video drivers and OS updates and see if things work better.

As for the exceptions you were seeing, that sounds like it could be a corrupted installation. We sometimes see problems with the update process, though it seems like this was a fresh installation in your case. You could try reinstalling from scratch to see if things get better.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the answer from Scott Barta:

I was running Debian 7.4 Wheezy with a special window manager (xmonad) and also had this problem with the blank window (but no error messages). However, switching window manager to gnome  solved this problem for me.

(I also tried adding the non-free ATI-drivers for my video card, but this had no effect)