# Can't install Android studio 1.0 in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, installation

I follow the step of the link

[How to install Android studio in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861558/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)

but always stuck like the guy below

[Android studio not working in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394945/android-studio-not-working-in-ubuntu)

and get the following message several times even if I download the SDK by myself to the android-studio folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTIgj.jpg

Does anyone know how to solve this problem while running ./studio.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give root permissions to studio.sh

cd /home/USERNAME/android-studio/bin/ (user name is login user)

sudo chmod 777 -R studio.sh

then just execute the studio.sh

./studio.sh